# How does Reverend Ethel know this?

Tags: sneaky-pete

How does Reverend Ethel know about Marius's brother's toe (S02E04 ending)? Is she supposed to be a real psychic? There were no other supernatural elements in the show.

Comment: I know about other people's brothers' toes, too (not a psychic). Can you tell us a bit more, especially about how she couldn't have known?